# Zepto JS : CSS doesn't apply to basic HTML template

Tags: javascript, css, html, templates, zepto

I attempting to load some HTML via a Zepto JS ajax call :

```
// inside $(docuement).ready...
$.get('dist/traffic-lights.html', function(response) {
  $(document.head).append(response);

  // in the page there are some DiVs to full fill..
  $('div.traffic-lights').each(function(idx, elm) {
    $(elm).html($('script#traffic-lights-template').html());
  });
}):
```

into dist/traffic-lights.html lives the template :

```
<script type="text/html" id="traffic-lights-template">
  <div class="cars-lights"> ... </div>
  <div class="buttons"> ... </div>
  <div class="pedestrians-lights"> ... </div> 
  <br class="clearfix" />
</script>
```

Everything seems ok ? the content is loaded, but CSS rules couldn't apply to inserted content ! How does it that possible ?

Comment: Not enough known. Please provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what css you are using or why it's not working as expected. Inspect the live html and associated style rules in browser dev tools for more clues

Comment: the CSS looks fine... In Chrome debugging tools the response script tag appears like a PLAIN string not as MARKUP... maybe this help ?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: perhaps this JSFiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/6k7hogkh/

Comment: and for the wjole comprehension of the problem : https://github.com/hefeust/dexm which is the JS (future es6) project, DEXM = Deux Ex Machina Finite State Machine

Comment: something wrong like bad characters in the css text ...https://jsfiddle.net/6k7hogkh/1/ Not sure what exactly I did but got it working. I added one rule , then they all worked, then removed that rule

Answer (score 0):

Effectively,

I have inserted a bad character into the CSS file...
How and what ? maybe a hazardous keystroke in my IDE...
Erased and rewroted my CSS file and no more trouble...

Thanks to charlietfl, my issue is SOLVED !

Regards.